# R: likelihood ratio test comparing two models, however missing data made the two models not in the same dimension

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a likelihood ratio test between two models.

```
glm.model1 <- glm(result ~ height + weight )
glm.model2 <- glm(result ~ hight + weight + speed + speed : height + speed : weight )
require(lmtest)    
a <- lrtest(glm.model1, glm.model2)
```

And I got the following error:

```
Error in lrtest.default(glm.model1, glm.model2) : 
models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset
```

I know some of my "speed" data are missing, but none of the height and weight data are missing, so since model 2 includes variable "speed" but model 1 doesn't, model 2 has datapoints got deleted by glm due to missingness.  So when I do likelihood ratio test between model 2 and model 1, the data dimension are not equal, and I end up with the error message like above. Is there a way I can look up what datapoints are deleted in model 2, so in my reduced model I can include some script to delete the same datapoint in order to keep the dimension of data same?

Here's what I've tried:

1) add  na.action = na.pass to keep all the missing data in the model 2, but it doesn't work.

2) tried:

```
glm.model1 <- glm(result ~ height + weight + speed - speed )
## This does work and it gets rid of the sample with "speed" missing, but this is like cheating.
```

Here's the summary of each model:

> summary(glm.model1)

```
......

    Null deviance: 453061  on 1893  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 439062  on 1891  degrees of freedom
AIC: 15698

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> summary(glm.model2)

```
......
    Null deviance: 451363  on 1887  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 437137  on 1882  degrees of freedom
  (6 observations deleted due to missingness)          ## This is what I want to look at:
AIC: 15652
 Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

How can I look at the observations that are deleted and write into the script to delete the same observations in the other model? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `is.na()` to check the missing in speed variable. Please see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/266199.html)for the possible solution.

Comment: There was also a spelling error in the second formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `subset` argument of the `glm()` function:

`glm.model1 <- glm(result ~ height + weight, subset=!is.na(speed) )`

Comment: Better would be to subset the columns in the most complex model: `!is.na(speed[ , c('height',  'weight', 'speed') ] )` or use `complete.cases` on same data argument.